# Android Studio1.1.0 Ndk Configuration

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk

I try to configure Ndk in Android Studio 1.1.0 on windows7. I create a simple project and in the terminal of android Studio, I wrote different commands but however all the times I got same errors.
Firstly I typed this one

C:\Users\omer\WorkSpaceAndroidSt\NDKSample\app\src\main>javah -d jni -classpath \F:\setups\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar;....\build\intermediates\classes\debug com
.example.omer.ndksample.MainActivity

and secondly this one

javah -verbose -classpath '\F:\setups\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\platforms\android-21\android.jar:\F:\setups\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs\android-support-v4.jar:\F:\setups\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat\libs\android-support-v7-appcompat.jar:..\build\intermediates\classes\debug' -d src\main\jni -force com.example.omer.ndksample.MainActivity

But both of them gave same error

Error: Could not find class file for 'com.example.omer.ndksample.MainActivity'.

Comment: Maybe because NDK coding is not supported in Android Studio yet?

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully set up NDK in Andriod studio 1.1.0 by following these steps:

1. Download android NDK from https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html
2. Unpack and move the unpacked content of the NDK folder to your preferred location on the hard drive
3. Open local.properties in the project’s root folder and set the NDK folder’s location. In my case, I have moved the NDK folder onto the C:\ drive so my path is ndk.dir=C:\android-ndk-r10d
4. Open build.gradle file in the module’s directory and set the correct path to ndk-build file. In the the windows environment you need to call ndk-build.cmd.

   task ndkBuild(type: Exec) {commandLine 'C:/android-ndk-r10d/ndk-build.cmd', '-B', '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath}

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response,what is absolute path and  do you have an idea that how can I create Jni folder and (so, dll, dylib) library